# Calculating the gain for adjusting sound level to X db

Tags: sound, real-time

I have a sound signal, and I would like to implement a simple realtime level control (for info, I am using Pure Data, but I'd like to know about the general case).

For this I thought of using the envelope amplitude (in dB) of the input `Vin_db`, calculated over a window of `N` samples ; use it to calculate the gain `G` to apply to the signal to get an output with amplitude `Vout_db`. (Disclaimer : I am very rusty with maths and decibels ...)

So I took the wikipedia formula for decibels :

`V_db = 10 * log10(P / P0)`

=>

`Vin_db = 10 * log10(Pin / P0)`

`Vout_db = 10 * log10(Pout / P0)`

And this gave me :

`Pout = Pin * 10^((Vout_db - Vin_db) / 10)`

=>

`G = 10^((Vout_db - Vin_db) / 10)`

However, this doesn't seem to work ... When I measure the output level it is not the expected `Vout`. Is there a fundamental flaw in my reasoning ? Or just a calculation error ?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Paul R I found the correct formula (I need a `20` instead of a `10`):

`G = 10^((Vout_db - Vin_db) / 20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert the voltages to dB, just calculate the required gain (as a factor) and then convert this to dB if necessary, i.e.

```
G = Vout / Vin                 # required gain (factor)

G_dB = 20 * log10(G)           # required gain (dB)
```

where

```
Vin = input voltage
Vout = output voltage
```

If you really want to work with dB throughout then you can do it like this (should give the same answer):

```
Vin_dB = 20 * log10(Vin)       # input voltage (dB)

Vout_dB = 20 * log10(Vout)     # output voltage (dB)

G_dB = Vout_dB - Vin_dB        # required gain (dB)

G = 10 ^ (G_dB / 20)           # required gain (factor)
```

Comment: But I don't know `Vout`! So how can I calculate `G`? How can I say at any point in time what `Vout` I am aiming at? I need to average the signal somehow ...

Comment: Can you clarify exactly that is is that you are trying to achieve ? It's not clear form your question. Do you want to apply a given dB increase, or achieve a particular signal level output, or what ?

Comment: I want to achieve a particular signal level output. And so actually the last formula work perfectly :) (I edited my question with your answer)

Comment: OK - and what is this required output level ? Is it a voltage, or what ?

Comment: What I want to do in the end is having a constant sound volume, no matter the input. So I guess output level is more like level in dB (ok ... maybe I am a bit confused with the units here).

Comment: Yes - I think you're confused with units. `dB` is just a *ratio*. `dB SPL` is an *absolute* sound level and is what people often mean colloquially when they say "dB". However to measure/control `dB SPL` you'll need a calibrated system and be able to control output gain (volume setting) etc.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure